# how do I define the or condition in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I'm new to programming and I am making a new simple app, but I'm struggling with something.

The app I'm making is a sort of calculator.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztW9y.png)

So what is does now is you type a percentage and a number in and it gives you the answer when you press the calculate button(Bereken), but now I want it to give me the percentage when I type something in the answer textview and the number textview.

I think that I have to make an "or" condition studio. I know that in Java you can use || to define "or", but how does it work in Android studio?

Comment: If you need help on code, you must provide some code. Otherwise we wont be able to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OR Condition works like this:

```
int x=5;
if(x=5 || x=10){
System.out.println("OR Condition passed");
}
```

Sample code:

```
int answer= Integer.parseInt(answerEditText.getText().toString());
int number= Integer.parseInt(numberEditext.getText().toString());
```

Use the reverse of the below formula to get the percentage from answer and number.

```
int k = (int)(value*(percentage/100.0f));
```

Comment: This is a better AND example, for an OR example you should probably do `int x=5;    if(x == 5 || x == 10){ // do something }`

Answer (score 1):

Android studio uses Java. Use `||` for `or`.